# Usage of the word "series"

Tags: word-usage

There is one word that confuses me a lot - *series*. What is hard for me to understand is that this word has only plural form while pretty related word *movie* has a singular form as well. So I would like to know whether the following sentences are correct:

1. What are your favorite series?
2. My favorite series are True Detective.
3. Have you seen the new series Taboo?

Is there a word with a singular form, like a *movie* but for TV series?
And the last question - should I add *TV* before *series* or is it implied?

Comment: Just because a word ends in *s* does not necessarily mean it is plural. *Series* is a borrowing from the Latin word *series*, meaning a sequence or succession— *-ies* in Latin is a suffix that creates a noun from an adjective, comparable to *-ness* or *-ity* in English; *species* is the other common word that follows this pattern. Interestingly, however, the cognate French word is *série*.

Comment: *"should I add TV between series or is it implied?"* - In question 3 it is implied by "seen", but in question 1 you should add TV otherwise somebody might respond with their favourite series of *books*. Also, if you say "What *are* your favourite series?" the "are" makes "series" plural, so somebody might answer "Doctor Who, True Detective, and Psych". If you say "What *is* your favourite series?" the "is" makes "series" singular, so then somebody would reply with only one thing.

Comment: @choster your comment about the Latin origin was really helpful, thanks

Comment: @nnnnnn so it is better to say *My favorite series IS True Detective*, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Series is *both* singular and plural. It depends on the sense, it takes a singular verb when it has a sense of *"one set"*, even though it's followed by a plural *of-phrase*

> A series of lectures is scheduled

In the 1st and 2nd examples, it refers to *one or more sets* of series. But for the third sentence, it can be interpreted as a singular or plural noun, depending on the context.

The TV is optional because it can be understood from the context.

---

Reference

*American Heritage Guide to Contemporary Usage and Style*

Answer (score 2):

An individual show that is part of a series is an **episode**: [one of the parts of a television or radio program that is given as a series over a period of time.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/episode)

There is also a special term for the first episode, especially if it is a trial to test audience reaction.  That is a **pilot**: [A television or radio programme made to test audience reaction with a view to the production of a series.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pilot)